# How to store mutiple column output in a for loop

Tags: greenplum

Designing a function to show column_name and count of null values

Expected o/p
Col_name,total count
abc  45
def  30
fgh 10

```
enter code here

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gtr_ops.f_column_validation()
RETURNS TABLE
(
column_name character varying(50),
total_blank_records bigint
 )
AS 
$BODY$
 DECLARE
 i record;
ecode CHARACTER VARYING(1000);
 vsql text;
 BEGIN
raise notice 'entering for loop';
for i IN (select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='xyz'
and table_name='xyz')
LOOP
--RAISE NOTICE '%', i.column_name;
column_name := i.column_name;
vsql := 'select count(*) from schema.tablename
 where '|| i.column_name||' is null
group by '|| i.column_name;
RAISE NOTICE '%', vsql;
EXECUTE vsql into total_blank_records;
RETURN NEXT;
END LOOP;
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   ecode := SQLSTATE||' Error Message:'|| SQLERRM;
   raise notice 'Err Msg: %',ecode;
   END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Error
Err Msg: 42703 Error Message:record "i" has no field "column_name"

Need guidance to solve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have tried your code and got a bit different error:

> Err Msg: 42702 Error Message:column reference "column_name" is ambiguous

Indeed, you use `column_name` in return type and in select (`select column_name from...`). When I changed to `select columns.column_name from...` it worked.

But then, you have to replace `schema.tablename` with proper value (just like you do with `i.column_name`):

First:

```
for i IN (select columns.table_schema, columns.table_name, columns.column_name from information_schema.columns where ...
```

Then:

```
vsql := 'select count(*) from ' || i.table_schema || '.' || i.table_name || '
```

But remember, that you have hard-coded table_schema and table_name to be `xyz.xyz` in your query in `for` loop.

I was testing with PostgreSQL 9.5.3.

Comment: Hi, Thx for the reply. Basically I need to pull 2 columns from the FOR loop select stmt output.    I hard code the value just not to expose the business table names

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add one line to my answer. Simply add those columns in 'SELECT': `select columns.table_schema, columns.table_name, columns.column_name from...` - I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hi, I added column keyword and it worked.  What is the significance of keyword columns.

Comment: It is the table name (without schema). Now it is clear that you get the column `column_name` from the table `columns` and there is no ambiguity.